# Is it possible to allocate huge array in c?

Tags: c

Hi all i want to use the following :

```
int i;
unsigned short int **graph;
graph = (unsigned short int**)malloc (sizeof(unsigned short int *) * 65535);
if (graph == NULL ) fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
for (i = 0; i < 65535; i++){
    graph[i] = (unsigned short int*)malloc (sizeof(unsigned short int) *65535);
    if (graph[i] == NULL ) fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
}
```

the size 65535 is constant
i need to build this size of graph 
is it possible?

will it help if i will split it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try ? What did it returned ?

Comment: It is a bit over 8 GB so on a 64-bit machine with sufficient memory it is possible.

Comment: It is possible if you have a lot of memory (and sometimes even if you don't), but you're not going to need that much.

Comment: its giving me my printing of "out of memory"

Comment: which one "out of memory". You have plenty in your code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be ~34GB? `(65535 * sizeof(int *)) * (65535 * sizeof(short))` = `(65535 * 4) * (65535 * 2)` = `34,358,689,800` on a 32bit machine.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `short` is likely to be 2 bytes (16 bits) and the pointer is almost certainly either 4 or 8 (likely 8 if this code is to work), so `65535 * 65535 * 2 + 65535 * 8`? Only the outer `malloc` allocates pointers.

Comment: @Arkuu Rechecked my math, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

There are four different issues to consider here:

1) The size of the argument of `malloc`. It is of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type that is at least 16 bits and large enough to hold the size of any object or the index of any array. In practice it tends to be the platform's native word size, i.e., 32 bits for 32-bit platforms, and 64 bits for 64-bit platforms, so you are likely to need at least a 32-bit platform, but this almost certainly the case unless developing for embedded (or very retro) systems.

One should also remember that the argument may overflow and you can silently end up *successfully* allocating less memory than you thought you'd get (e.g., you may effectively call `malloc(65534)` when you thought you were calling `malloc(2 * 65535)`). But in this case it is very unlikely to be an issue for any platform capable of allocating this amount of memory.

2) Whether the `malloc` calls succeed. You are already checking for this, so simply running the code will answer this. You are allocating over 8 GB† of memory here, so it is likely that it will fail unless compiled for 64 bits (since the maximum addressable memory for 32 bits is 4 GB).

3) Whether you can actually use all the memory you've allocated. Some operating systems will overcommit memory and allow you to allocate much more memory than is actually available. You may run into trouble if you actually try to *use* all the memory you've allocated. This depends on the OS and the amount of memory actually available, possibly including swap.

4) Whether it is practical for the machine the program is run on to actually have that much data in memory. Even if the `malloc` calls succeed and the OS lets you use the memory allocated, it is still over 8 GB, which means that a typical machine should probably have at least 12 GB of RAM installed to accommodate this, the OS, and other programs. Otherwise it may swap like crazy, despite theoretically working.

You have revealed in comments that you are running a 64-bit machine with 4 GB of RAM installed, so if you compile for 64 bits the first two points are not an issue, but point 3 may be, and point 4 almost certainly will be. So, either install more RAM or figure out a different way to handle the data (e.g., if you are storing a graph as per the variable name, perhaps it is often sparse enough that you don't need to allocate for the worst case).

† “over 8 GB” comes from `65535 * sizeof(short *) + 65535 * 65535 * sizeof(short)`, where `sizeof(short)` is very likely to be `2`, and `sizeof(short *)` (the pointer size) either 4 or 8. There is also some extra overhead for `malloc`'s bookkeeping, but still it rounds to “over 8 GB”.

Some stylistic observations:

- It would be better style to use one of the types from `stdint.h` if you want specifically 16 bits, e.g., `uint16_t` or `uint_least16_t`
- You should not cast the return value of `malloc` in C (unlike in C++)
- You can replace `sizeof(unsigned short int *)` with `sizeof(*graph)` and `sizeof(unsigned short int)` with `sizeof(**graph)` to avoid repetition (and allow you to change the type of `graph` without changing the `malloc` calls)
- You don't need the `int` in `unsigned short int`

Answer (score 0):

Max allowed size will be range of integer. So if you are using 16 bit OS max size is 65535, if you are using 32 bit OS size will be 4,294,967,295.

Comment: i am using microsoft visual studio 2010

Comment: 64 bit Windows 7 with 4 GB ram

Comment: In the code as shown you can make every single `malloc` call even on 32-bit, but the total memory allocated exceeds 8 GB so you are likely to need a 64-bit OS for all of the calls to succeed, and even if the calls succeed an OS may overcommit the memory and it will fail when you actually try to use it. And even if it works, with 4 GB memory using 8 GB would obviously lead to swapping.

Comment: @Tomer Working fine with my VS compiler.

Comment: how could i compare mine to yours? maybe its configurable in the visual studio?

Comment: @Tomer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx (but understand that you are allocating over 8 GB of memory and you just said you have only 4 GB installed, think about it… =)

Comment: @Tomer Oh no.. wait.. you are allocating `graph[i] = (unsigned short int*)malloc (sizeof(unsigned short int) *65535);` 65535 times, that's huge memory. You will get Out of Memory. Are you sure you want to allocate memory in loop?

Comment: i dont care how it will be allocated excatly (loop or not) i just need this size of an array for my data, what is my possiblitis?

Comment: i will try it on vnc server and see how thats comes up, thanks

Comment: @Tomer I think possibilities is written in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of non-arrayed data is `SIZE_MAX`.  `SIZE_MAX` is *at least* 65535.

`SIZE_MAX` is type `size_t` which is often the same type as `unsigned` but may be different.

The single largest allocation available using `malloc()` is `SIZE_MAX`.

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

`sizeof(unsigned short int *) * 65535` may fail due to integer math overflow.

To allocate an array larger than `SIZE_MAX` (but each element is still <= `SIZE_MAX`), use `calloc()`.

```
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
unsigned short int **graph = calloc(65535u, sizeof *graph);
```

Comment: Note that `calloc` is often not capable of allocating more memory than `malloc`, and indeed many implementations just call `malloc` internally. One benefit is that it can check for overflow in the multiplication, but in that case it will often simply fail (return `NULL`).

Comment: @Arkku Agree `calloc()` _may_ not be able to allocate more than `malloc()`.  But if the need exceeds what `malloc()` can provide, `calloc()` may work.  This is popular in 16-bit `int` segment:offset architectures.

Comment: Yes, you are right, nothing in the standard precludes `calloc` from working this way as far as I can see, but I just wanted to point out that it is not guaranteed capable of allocating more than `malloc` (and especially not `SIZE_MAX * SIZE_MAX`). Also the OP is using 64-bit Windows so `calloc` is unlikely to help if `malloc` fails. =)